# Association bonus +100

Tags: support, association-bonus

At first I had an account in stack overflow of reputation 221. The I joined Mathematica and got the reputation of 101 in Mathematica. When I came back to stack overflow I found that my stack overflow account had also received +100 association bonus. I then decided to join Physics and received 101 in Physics but this time my stack overflow account was not given +100 . Why did this happen??

Comment: So you're complaining about free rep? :P

Comment: You only get the bonus *once*.

Comment: :) Then I will join every site.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work):

> you *associate accounts* of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation: **+100** on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

You only get the bonus on Stack Overflow once, not for each site you join.